# Theme.AppCompat not working in real device

Tags: android

I made an app with minSDK=7 and set Theme.AppCompat to get a dark theme. Everything works fine in 2.1 emulator but when I install the app on a real device (Tested on a device with android 4.1) the theme is Light. Why does this happen?

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">      
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
```

And the manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Is your target SDK version same as android 4.1?

Comment: No Target is the maximum SDK version (4.4). Is it supposed to be 4.1?
I want the theme to be the same in all devices.